# Using Gettext for multilingual site in php doesn't work

Tags: php, gettext

I'm trying to make a multilingual site in PHP using `gettext`.

I'm using PHP7.1 (no way of upgrading), and have enabled *gettext.so* in my *php.ini*.

See: http://corbeauperdu.ddns.net/phpinfo.php

I've read the documentation and followed examples, but for some reason, it won't translate at all to my French language.

My PO file and *test.php* files are as follows:

```
/prestadesk/include/locales/fr/LC_MESSAGES/prestadesk.po:
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: fr\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

msgid "This page will show the dashboard"
msgstr "Cette page affichera le tableau de bord"


/prestadesk/templates/test.php:
<?php
$lang='fr';
$domain = 'prestadesk';
$codeset = 'UTF-8';
$locales_dir = '../include/locales'; // need to go up on directory from here to get into the include/locales

// here we define the global system locale given the found language
putenv('LANG='.$lang);

// this might be useful for date functions (LC_TIME) or money formatting (LC_MONETARY), for instance
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);

// this will make Gettext look for $locales_dir/<lang>/LC_MESSAGES/prestadesk.mo
bindtextdomain($domain, $locales_dir);

// indicates in what encoding the file should be read
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $codeset);

// here we indicate the default domain the gettext() calls will respond to
textdomain($domain);

// test translate
echo gettext("This page will show the dashboard");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the problem:

The server the website resides on NEEDS to have the locale installed for the desired $lang !!!

On the server, check the installed locales with:

```
locale -a
```

If your desired locale is not listed, you must edit **/etc/locale.gen** and uncomment yours. Example:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 
fr_FR ISO-8859-1
fr_FR@euro ISO-8859-15
```

Then, generate and install that locale:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

Once this is done, you'll be able to use gettext() properly.